# SQLSRV: group by one column and sum by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a difficult query to do =)

the **Stops** table have the following columns

```
Id, Area, SubArea, Date, StopNumber, DownTime
```

I would like to have a result like this: (I'll try to describe..)

```
    Area, SubArea, SUM(StopNumber appened in january) as GEN,
     SUM(StopNumber appened in february) as FEB, etc..
FROM Stops
GROUP BY Area, SubArea
```

Could anyone help me?
thank you :)

Comment: I would consider changing the approach: the output should be something like `Area, SubArea, Month, SUM(StopNumber)` and then you can filter by month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT Area, SubArea,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
SUM(CASE Month(Date) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Dec]
FROM Stops
GROUP BY Area, SubArea
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the approach I suggested you in the comment, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT Area, SubArea, MONTH(Date) AS Month, SUM(StopNumber) AS NumStops
    FROM Stops
    GROUP BY Area, SubArea, MONTH(Date)
```